# How to set the current date in the html report ("Start Time" section) in JMeter?

Tags: date, jmeter, report

I try to generate a dashboard report from JMeter results and faced the issue, some graphs have an incorrect elapsed time (00:00:00):

[image: incorrect elapsed time]

Also, I saw that "Start Time" is incorrect ("1/1/70 2:00 AM"), but at the same time "End Time" is incorrect:

[image: correct elapsed time]

I assume that this incorrect date is a cause of incorrect graphs. How I can fix it?

P.S. I ran the test from non-GUI mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [`reportgenerator.properties`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/reportgenerator.properties#L72)

```
# Used to generate a report based on a date range
# If jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format does not contain year
# then use 1970 as year
```

Looking into [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

> `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format` Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files.
>   Legitimate values: `none`, `ms`, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat.
>   Defaults to: `ms` No
>
> `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format` Defaults to: `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

So my expectation is that you need to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

and on next test execution you should see "normal" start date in the reporting dashboard.

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)